# error al convertir int to intPtr C#

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un programa para ocultar la ventana de notepad, pero tengo este error
Error   CS1503  Argumento 1: no se puede convertir de 'int' a 'System.IntPtr'

el error estaria en `handleR = pr.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32();`

```
                        int handleR;
                        Process[] processRunning = Process.GetProcesses();
                        foreach (Process pr in processRunning)
                        {
                            if (pr.ProcessName == "notepad")
                            {
                                
                                handleR = pr.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32();
                                ShowWindow(handleR, SW_HIDE);
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: ¿Es necesario convertirlo? ¿No puedes pasarle el `MainWindowHandle` directamente a la función?

Answer (score 0):

El error

> CS1503 Argumento 1: no se puede convertir de 'int' a 'System.IntPtr'

te dice que no puede convertir el primer parámetro.

El problema está en `ShowWindow`, que espera un parámetro de tipo `IntPtr` y tu le das un `int`.

Según la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr?view=net-6.0), el tipo `IntPtr` representa un puntero o un identificador.

Teniendo presente la teoría, las direcciones de memoria son de cierto tamaño. En el caso de un procesador de 32 bits serán de 32 bits y en uno de 64 bits, 64 bits.

Para poder representar un puntero (o dirección de memoria), `IntPtr` varía su tamaño en función del de las direcciones de memoria.

En C#, el tipo `int` tiene 32 bits y el tipo `long` 64.

La conversión probablemente esté fallando porque te encuentras en un sistema de 64 bits y el tipo `int` se queda corto para contener la dirección. En su lugar, usa un `long`. Puedes convertirlo también de la siguiente manera:

```
IntPtr p = ...
long l = (long)p;
p = (IntPtr)l;
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18173246

Comment: Tengo 32 bits XD

Comment: A caso `ShowWindow(pr.MainWindowHandle, SW_HIDE)` no soluciona tu problema?

Comment: si, muchas gracias